# Функциональное программирование на Python и словари (dict)

Tags: python, python-3.x

В целях оптимизации кода пытаюсь оформить небольшие куски кода в более выразительный вид, в некоторых местах не очень получается.

Есть код, в котором создается словарь с ключем и значением:

```
x = {}

for i in range(5):
    x[i] = 1
```

Используя list comprehension, и если бы переменная **x** была списком, можно было бы поступить как то так:

```
[x.append([i, 1]) for i in range(5)]
```

Однако, ключ со значением присваиваются как x[value] = value, таким образом следующий код дает синтаксическую ошибку:

```
[x[i] = 1 for i in range(5)]
```

Подскажите, как реализовать добавление ключа - значения в функциональном программировании (python 3.x).

Comment: для списка лучше: `x += [[i, 1] for i in range(5)]` использовать, так как `x.append()` всегда `None` -- ни к чему создавать список из одних `None` таким способом.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для словарей тоже есть генератор:

```
dct = {i: 1 for i in range(5)}
print(dct)
```

Выведет

```
{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}
```

https://habrahabr.ru/post/224163/

Если вы хотите именно добавить значения к существующему словарю, используйте функцию `update()`:

```
dct = {}
dct.update({(i, 1) for i in range(5)})
print(dct)
```

Выведет то же самое.

Answer (score 2):

+к вышеперечисленным способам

```
# fromkeys создает словарь из ключей, с дефолтным знечением
x = {}.fromkeys(range(5), 1)
# {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}
# setdefault создаст ключ k, только если его нету в словаре x
for k in range(10): x.setdefault(k, 2)
# {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2}
```